# What Is Bundle Identifier For Dreamweaver?

Tags: macos, dreamweaver

For Mac Os X Terminal I am trying to launch Dreamweaver by below code:

```
open -b "com.adobe.Dreamweaver"
```

But it does not help.

What is the correct bundle identifier for Dreamweaver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
open -a "Dreamweaver CS 5"
```

would work. If you really need to know the bundle identifier, do the following:

```
$ cd  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/
$ ./lsregister -dump | grep -i adobe
```

`lsregister` is a nice utility to know, if you need to access the `LaunchServices` database sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `Info.plist` file in the `Contents` folder of that application.

There you find something like:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.apple.TextEdit</string>
```

See also [How to Find a Bundle Identifier](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=71).

Comment: Thanks but there is no plist file for Dreamweaver CS5.